# How can I center a UIActivityIndicatorView in a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to put a UIActivityIndicatorView inside each collection view cell as it downloads its image. I have it appearing in each cell, but it refuses to center itself. It stays in the top left corner. How can I get it to center itself properly?

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
extension UIView {

    func showActivityIndicator(onView: UIView, withIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView) {
        withIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: onView.frame.midX - 20, y: onView.frame.midY - 20, width: 40, height: 40)
        withIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
        withIndicator.center = onView.center
        onView.addSubview(withIndicator)
        withIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

I call that function inside cellForItemAtIndexPath like:

```
showActivityIndicator(onView: cell.contentView, withIndicator: activityInd)
```

But nothing I do will move it from the top left corner. Any advice?

Comment: Why do you pass a view to a method that is an extension to `UIView`? You should call this as `cell.contentView.showActivityIndicator(activityInd)` and the method signature should be `func showActivityIndicator(_ indicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView)`. Then all references to `onView` in the method should be replaced with `self`.

Comment: I found that online really quick, but good point, I changed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
withIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
```

Comment: Thanks @CodyLucas glad that i could help, would you mind accepting the answer as correct :)

Comment: Yes, it just needs a minute before I'm allowed to.

Comment: This is not correct for the given method. `self` should be replaced with `onView`.

Comment: it's working but don't know why onView.center won't make it while CGPointMake will yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add contraints to center it. For example use [NSLayoutAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor).

You need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, to set your constraints. And after adding it to the view set the constraints (hints in the code comments):

```
extension UIView {

    func showActivityIndicator(onView: UIView, withIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView) {
        withIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: onView.frame.midX - 20, y: onView.frame.midY - 20, width: 40, height: 40)
        withIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge

        // set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false to set your constraints
        withIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        onView.addSubview(withIndicator)
        withIndicator.startAnimating()

        // add the constraints to center the indicator
        withIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: onView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        withIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: onView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using constraints (aka auto layout):

```
indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
"your cell".addSubview(indicator)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicator, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
                                                 toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 250)

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicator, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
                                                  toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicator, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicator, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([widthConstraint, heightConstraint, xConstraint, yConstraint])
```